# How can I count and display the number of brush strokes in the current document?

Tags: adobe, photoshop, photoshop-script

I was looking for a way to be able to count and display the number of strokes made in the current document using the Photoshop brush tool.

I have very basic programming knowledge, but Photoshop scripting is confusing and there doesn't seems to be much in terms of learning material out there. Didn't get a clue out of the Photoshop scripting guide pdf.

I assume if you could query the starting event of the brush stroke tool and add it to an array, could then display current size of the array?

Comment: There's no 'brush stroke event' in Photoshop. Photoshop Generator has a `documentChanged` event, but it's slow and plus Generator is documented even worse than JSX or CEP

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to make use of the documentChanged event for this. Alternatively, there's an option to output a history log from Photoshop to a text file, which records the use of the brush tool. I'm thinking I could used that to count the number of brush strokes. How would i go about bringing that information back into photoshop to display it in realtime?

Comment: If this is for someone else's machine, you'll need to maje sure the history log is turned on, that path where the log is created exists: there are no DOM commands for that  so you'll have to hack your way with AM. Then you'll create a CEP panel that'd read that file, parse it and display the data. I'm not sure how to handle file updates, maybe node `fs` module can 'watch' the file and read it every time it updates...

Comment: Thanks..i'll investigate the approach you've suggested. Sorry, but what does AM stand for?

Comment: Action Manager: recordable JS code from Photoshop. It's quite difficult to read but it can do things DOM can't

Comment: Ah got it, cool